# How to plot efficient frontier with pypfopt plotting

Tags: python, plot

Hey guysm someone could help me?
I'm new here and in python codying to, so i'm beginner level.

I'm was trying plot my efficient frontier using pypfopt lib and i'm got some troubles with the parameters in Plotting.plot_efficient_frontier command that is used to plot the graph.

I added the picture of my code in the post

```py
#importando as libs
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib as plt


from pypfopt.expected_returns import mean_historical_return
from pypfopt.risk_models import CovarianceShrinkage

#definindo o período de análise
start = dt.datetime(2019,1,1)
end = dt.datetime(2019,12,31)

#asset tickers
tickers = ["ITUB4.SA","B3SA3.SA","PETR4.SA","ABEV3.SA","ELET3.SA"]

#getting the data
carteira = web.DataReader(tickers,"yahoo",start,end)

#craindo outro dataframe só com os proços de feachamento ajustados

prices = carteira['Adj Close']

#expected returns
#covariance matrix
e_r = mean_historical_return(prices)
cov_matrix = CovarianceShrinkage(prices).ledoit_wolf()

from pypfopt.efficient_frontier import EfficientFrontier

#border problem solution
#selectiong portfolio with better sharpe ratio
ef = EfficientFrontier(e_r, cov_matrix)
weights = ef.max_sharpe()

from pypfopt import Plotting
Plotting.plot_efficient_frontier(ef ,points=100 , show_assets = True)




[n ][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaeJI.png
```

Comment: Hello Pedro Ivo, tell us, what have you done so far? Show us your code and we can help you.

Comment: to see my code click in te letter "n" below my text. has a letter n with the my code links. I'm sorry, I dont know how to edit my questions. doens't has any button

Comment: Hello Pedro, here it's preferred to put your code in the question. Below your question you'll see text links: share-edit, just click on it. On the editor you have you'll see a bar with buttons like bold, italic, etc. One is used to insert code.

Comment: @Manu, I did what you said. my code is there

Answer (score 2):

try it in lowercase() like:

from pypfopt import plotting